# Jsonix Element and value restriction

Tags: marshalling, jsonix

I am using JSONIX to marshall and unmarshall XML received from other system. The XML I want to marshall and unmarshall

> `<charge>`
>         392.2361
>           `<formatted>`392.24`</formatted>`
>               `</charge>`

I still cannot figure out how to unmarshall the value "392.2361". Any one with any idea? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need here is a [mixed property](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix/wiki/Properties#mixed-properties).

```
{
    type: 'classInfo',
    localName: 'MyType',
    propertyInfos: [{
        type: 'elementRef',
        name: 'charge',
        elementName: 'formatted',
        collection : true,
        mixed: true
    }]
}
```

What you'll as value get is something like:

```
[ '392.2361', { name: { localPart: 'formatted' }, value: '392.24' }]
```

Not tested, no guarantees but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Finally applied it properly. Thank you #lexicore

Here is my implementation for the mixed property

```
{
     type: 'classInfo',
     localName: 'ItemizedForDateType', //<date>
     propertyInfos:[
            {
                type: 'element',
                name: 'priceTextType',
                elementName: 'price',
                typeInfo: 'DOTWXML.PriceFormattedType'
            },
            {
                type: 'element',
                name: 'priceMinSellTextType',
                elementName: 'priceMinimumSelling',
                typeInfo: 'DOTWXML.PriceFormattedType'
            }
    ]
},
{
     type: 'classInfo',
     localName: 'PriceFormattedType',                           
     propertyInfos:[
        {
            type: 'elementRef',
            name: 'charge',
            elementName: 'formatted',
            collection : true,
            mixed: true
        },
     ]
}
```

And the result of unmarshall is something like the following:

```
    "itemizedForDateType": [
      {
        "TYPE_NAME": "DOTWXML.ItemizedForDateType",
        "priceTextType": {
          "TYPE_NAME": "DOTWXML.PriceFormattedType",
          "charge": [
            "236.8738",
            {
              "name": {
                "namespaceURI": "",
                "localPart": "formatted",
                "prefix": "",
                "key": "formatted",
                "string": "formatted"
              },
              "value": "236.87"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

I made a mistake by removing "**collection : true**" and was getting "**{}**" after unmarshall. Once I realized the "**collection : true**" was *required*, put it in the context and everything unmarshalled properly.